# Check whether a FontStretch exists for a specific FontFamily

Tags: .net, wpf

I have some text editing functionality in my tool, which allows the user to select properties of the current font, including FontStretch. I'm trying to use a Converter to check whether specific FontStretch values are available by creating a TypeFace with the FontFamily and FontStretch. Unfortunately, even if the FontStretch isn't supported (and falls back on one of the other values), it still reports the Typeface being created with the FontStretch I've specified. Here's the code I have so far for that test:

```
private static bool IsFontStretchAvailable(FontFamily font, FontStretch stretch)
{
    Typeface testFont = new Typeface(font, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, stretch);
    return (0 == FontStretch.Compare(stretch, testFont.Stretch)); 
}
```

This is always true, regardless. Is there some way to determine what FontStretch values are valid? I know that there are ways around using FontStretch with LayoutTransform, which I may also support in the future, but I want to use the FontStretch typefaces where possible, as I believe it may give a better visual result in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the best way is to check the Fonts.SystemFonts collection, which is a complete list of valid TypeFaces. Here's the code for that test:

```
Typeface testFont = Fonts.SystemTypefaces.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FontFamily.Equals(font) && x.Stretch.Equals(stretch));
return testFont != null;
```

That does what I want, but I will probably end up using the Fonts.SystemFonts to create my own dictionary of FontFamilies with valid Weights and Stretches for each, to do the lookup instead of this search. If someone has a better method, please let me know.